# SQL Server: how to turn rows into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an output that looks like this:

```
colA | colB | Value
A    | a    | 46
A    | b    | 8979
A    | C    | 684168468
B    | a    | 68546841
B    | b    | 456846
B    | c    | 468468
C    | a    | 684684
.    | .    |  .
.    | .    |  .
```

The list goes on and on. Colb repeats a sequence of a,b,c, and there could be duplicate values, but I guess it doesn't matter, since it will have different values for colB.

I want to make it look like this

```
col A | a        | b      | c
A     | 46       | 8979   | 684168468
B     | 68546841 | 456846 | 468468
C     | 684684
```

I know I can do it with pivot table, but I want to do it in sql server, because I have so many rows. 
Can anyone tell me how to accomplish this?

Comment: Have a look at [Pivot](https://technet.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: this is easy to understand, short and sweet: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/500811/Simple-Way-To-Use-Pivot-In-SQL-Query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple PIVOT:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
PIVOT (SUM(Value) FOR colB IN (a,b,c)) P
```

---

**Example**

```
WITH Src AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    ('A', 'a', 46       ),
    ('A', 'b', 8979     ),
    ('A', 'C', 684168468),
    ('B', 'a', 68546841 ),
    ('B', 'b', 456846   ),
    ('B', 'c', 468468   ),
    ('C', 'a', 684684   )) T(colA, colB, Value)
)
SELECT *
FROM Src
PIVOT
(SUM(Value) FOR colB IN (a,b,c)) P
```

**Result:**

```
colA a           b           c
---- ----------- ----------- -----------
A    46          8979        684168468
B    68546841    456846      468468
C    684684      NULL        NULL
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: I've got one question, what if I didn't know the values in colB. There are so many. I can't specify them all. and some of them don't have values.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to improve Pawel's solution by using [dynamic SQL pivot query](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-dynamic-pivot-table-example-code.aspx) as follows

This will take task of you to create the column list from possible data values from second column

```
DECLARE @values varchar(max)
SELECT @values =
 STUFF(
 (
  select distinct ',[' + col2 + ']'
  from tblData
  for xml path('')
 ),
 1,1,'')

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)
SELECT @SQL = N'
select
 *
from tblData
PIVOT (
 sum(val)
 FOR col2
 IN (
  ' + @values + '
 )
) PivotTable 
'
--print @SQL
exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Output is as seen in below screenshot
[image]

For sample data:

```
create table tblData (col1 varchar(5),col2 varchar(5),val bigint)
insert into tblData values
    ('A', 'a', 46       ),
    ('A', 'b', 8979     ),
    ('A', 'C', 684168468),
    ('B', 'a', 68546841 ),
    ('B', 'b', 456846   ),
    ('B', 'c', 468468   ),
    ('C', 'a', 684684   )
```